# Why should I free the result of PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why should I free the result of PHP and MySQL using `mysql_free_result()`?

And what is the difference whether I free the result or not?

Should I always free the result from a MySQL query result specially in CRUD?

Thanks for answering my questions?

Answer (score 6):

Freeing results in PHP is more or less to tell both the server and PHP to drop the resultset returned from a query. It is sort of a mean to free up memory especially when you have many queries or queries that return large resultsets.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I'm kinda noob in php development. So its a best practice to free the result query of SELECT statement only? or other statements must also be freed like INSERT and UPDATE? Thank you again.

Comment: likeI said, it is more recommended when you have large amount of queries or queies with large result set. otherwise it's perfectly fine.

Comment: `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s don't have result sets, so you shouldn't have to free them.

Answer (score -1):

On exit, your script cleans up your results automatically.
In a web environment it's only necessary if you've extremely limited memory constraints.

Comment: I am aware this post was made 5 years ago, but I am just curious as to why it received a downvote, since I thought that this is pretty much true.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jazzbassrob The answer provided manages to be both too general and too specific without fully answering the questions. After providing this answer, it goes on to give advice that is technically inaccurate and only useful if you have no idea what mysql_free_result() does and would rather get general advice than actually try understand it so you can make a good decision on your own. It would have been better as a comment.